# Visual studio as PIC IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2013, makefile, ide

I want to be able to use VS2013 as an IDE, for editing my PIC-microchip.
I have MPLAB X IDE 2.20 and the oppropriate compiler installed, and it works OK, but the SVN/GIT client and autocomplete is not so useful as the one i am accustomed to.
Someone has asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627486/embedded-code-development-especially-for-pic-with-c18-in-visual-studio), and the answer said that it is possible, but not how.

When compiling in MPLAB, the following is written in output:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-PIC32MX795F512L.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make -f nbproject/Makefile-PIC32MX795F512L.mk dist/PIC32MX795F512L/production/project.X.production.hex
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe" -g -x c++ -c -mprocessor=32MX150F128D -frtti -fexceptions -fno-check-new -fenforce-eh-specs -MMD -MF build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/main.o.d -o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/main.o main.cpp 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe" -g -x c++ -c -mprocessor=32MX150F128D -frtti -fexceptions -fno-check-new -fenforce-eh-specs -MMD -MF build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/configuration_bits.o.d -o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/configuration_bits.o configuration_bits.cpp 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe" -g -x c++ -c -mprocessor=32MX150F128D -frtti -fexceptions -fno-check-new -fenforce-eh-specs -MMD -MF build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/interrupts.o.d -o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/interrupts.o interrupts.cpp 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe" -g -x c++ -c -mprocessor=32MX150F128D -frtti -fexceptions -fno-check-new -fenforce-eh-specs -MMD -MF build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/system.o.d -o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/system.o system.cpp 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe" -g -x c++ -c -mprocessor=32MX150F128D -frtti -fexceptions -fno-check-new -fenforce-eh-specs -MMD -MF build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/user.o.d -o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/user.o user.cpp 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin\xc32-g++.exe"   -mprocessor=32MX150F128D  -o dist/PIC32MX795F512L/production/DDG.X.production.elf build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/main.o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/configuration_bits.o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/exceptions.o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/interrupts.o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/system.o build/PIC32MX795F512L/production/user.o          -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--defsym=_min_heap_size=4096,--defsym=_min_stack_size=4096
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.33\bin"\\xc32-bin2hex dist/PIC32MX795F512L/production/DDG.X.production.elf
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is for AVR, this might help you with configuring VS2013 for PIC: http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Visual-Studio-2010-to-Compile-AVR-Hex-Files/